# Make Doctrine to add entities in original order

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$evaluation->getQuestions()->clear();

foreach ($questions_data as $data) {
    $id = (int) $data['id'];        

    if ($id > 0) {
        $question = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->find($id);

        if ($question)
            $evaluation->getQuestions()->add($question);
    }
}

$em->persist($evaluation);
$em->flush();
```

Here is `$questions_data` — `array(['id' => 2], ['id' => 1], ['id' => 3])`.
And here is how doctrine persist questions to database:
[image]

So, how to make doctrine to don't sort questions?
`Evaluation` entity has `ManyToMany` relation with the `Question` entity, so `ORDER BY` couldn't help, because table `evaluations_questions` was created automatically by `Doctrine` and don't have field `id`.

Comment: There are _no_ database vendors that _guaranty_ that the order in which records are stored is the _same_ order in which they are fetched. In some cases storage doesn't even have an order (like the way you think). The _only_ way to fetch rows in a particular order is to use an `ORDER BY` clause in a `SELECT` query. Doctrine cannot change this.

Comment: "And here is how doctrine persist questions to database" -> No! This is the order MySQL returns the rows when PhpMyAdmin queries them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you flush newly persisted items in Doctrine, Doctrine must determine which order to commit them to the database using an internal function [`getCommitOrder`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1127). The purpose of that function is to ensure that an object's dependencies are committed before the object itself is committed. This is done to comply with any foreign key constraints that might be set up. As you observed, a consequence of ordering data to commit like this is that you lose the ability to finely tune the order that items are committed - *this isn't necessarily a bad thing*.

In SQL the only way you can order your results is by issuing a query with `ORDER BY`. If you choose not to specify a sorting method, you cannot expect the results to come back in any particular order. The [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html) explain this:

> If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, **but it must not be relied on**.

In other words, it shouldn't matter what order the content is stored in your database.

In your problem, the order by which questions appear to a user is an issue. You can't allow the questions to appear randomly in an evaluation - they must follow a preset order. Frankbeen touches on this in a comment, but the best solution would be to add a new field on the `Evaluation` that stores an [array](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types) of the `Questions` in the proper order. The order can then be read when you present the evaluation to a user.

---

If you *absolutely must* order them in a specific order in your database, you should be able to just flush the new objects individually as they are persisted instead of scheduling them to be flushed together.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$evaluation->getQuestions()->clear();

foreach ($questions_data as $data) {
    $id = (int) $data['id'];        

    if ($id > 0) {
        $question = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->find($id);

        if ($question) {
            $evaluation->getQuestions()->add($question);
            $em->persist($evaluation);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware, this will take much more time to complete and is a pretty poor solution to your problem.

Comment: `flush()` is a quite expensive operation, you might get better performance by using `flush($evaluation)` or `flush($question)` to avoid flushing all entities every time.

Answer (score 1):

new records are stored at the end of the table, always. If you want to get the questions in natural order (by id) then you should use ORDER BY. I guess that the Evaluation entity has a OneToMany relation with the Question entity.

In that case you can simple add a optional annotation above the $questions property in the Evalutation entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $questions;
```

Comment: Evaluation entity has ManyToMany relation with the Question entity, so `ORDER BY` couldn't help, because table `evaluations_questions` was created automatically by `Doctrine` and don't have field `id`.

Comment: it works also for ManyToMany fields but i think you will have to change id to question_id in that case. See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby

Comment: That is my my problem: doctrine is saving new fields already sorted, not as you described (new record to the end of the table). Also i've tried to persist & flush after each `foreach` iteration — it didn't helped.

Comment: Actually the discussion should not be about the order that records are stored into the database. You must sort them when you retrieve them from the database. If necessary you even add a extra column that stores the sequence (or order).

Comment: How can i add extra column to auto-created by doctrine table?

Comment: You can just insert a new property with the right annotations. Then you could create an extra column with same name in phpMyAdmin. But better would be to use the commandline: php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle AND php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Answer (score 0):

The `EntityManagerInterface` have transaction support and I recommend using that feature for all multi statement operations. This will allow you to create multiple statements and commit them in order all att once. Each statement will be executed in the order that they were added and if one statement fails, no changes will be done to the database at all.

That being said, all database implementations might not store data in the order that they were added, so if data is expected to be returned in a certain order, you should always query with `ORDER BY` explicitly as mentioned in another reply.

Say that you want to abort the operation if you encounter a question with an unknown id. This can quite easily be accomplished with something like the following:

```
function storeQuestions($questions_data): bool
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->beginTransaction();

    $evaluation->getQuestions()->clear();

    foreach ($questions_data as $data) {
        $id = (int) $data['id'];        

        if ($id > 0) {
            $question = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Question')->find($id);

            if ($question) {
                $evaluation->getQuestions()->add($question);
                $em->persist($evaluation);
            } else {
                $em->rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    $em->flush();
    $em->commit();

    return true; // Success
}
```

Comment: You should `flush()` *before* `commit()`, otherwise you're committing... nothing, and `flush()` outside a transaction. I took the liberty to update your code so as to not confuse readers that may stumble upon your answer.