# Children entities stored in reverse order when changes are persisted

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an Entity (*Offer*) with some children sub-entities (*LandingPage*) in a OneToMany.
When I create this offer with its landingPages, those are saved in a reverse order.

The same behavior happens also with different entities in the same app.

I tried a:

```
dump($offer->getLandingPages());
$em->flush();
dd($offer->getLandingPages());
```

And you can see the output here, IDs are stored in a reverse order:
[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Just as a general rule you should never rely on id's being in some particular order.  Think of them as unique identifiers and save yourself considerable downstream grief.  If you need the entities in a particular order then sort them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Doctrine to add entities in original order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766709/make-doctrine-to-add-entities-in-original-order)

Comment: @yivi thanks, basically they say to `flush()` at each insert, I've thought about that as well, another workaround is just to issue an `array_reverse()`, but I was curious why that happens, it has worked fine for years until we updated recently to symfony6